# Using HttpClient in cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-4

Due to some requirement, i need to move code with System.Net.Http.HttpClient from controller to cshtml file. However, it seems that I can't invoke System.Net.Http.HttpClient in cshtml file.

So, my question is how to invoke httpclient in cshtml file?

As for the interest of why i need to invoke HttpClient in cshtml file, it is because I need to consume the same external API for pages which use the same layout. This means that if i need to include it in controller, I would have to include in almost every controller (over hundred) and I feel that this is redundant.

Scenario: Invoking web api to return list of menu and display in cshtml file with Layout="CustomLayout.cshtml"

I hope that the scenario given explain well why i need to invoke httpclient in cshtml. I do appreciate if there is any better alternative.

Comment: I still don't see any reason for you to put HttpClient or API calls on your pages in cshtml, this is dangerous and just breaks your architecture to pieces, consider using RenderAction or ViewModels for this

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the external API for pages that use the same layout (or not) without moving that code from the controller to the View.. if you do so you will be breaking the MVC architecture design. The view should only be concerned about displaying and rendering data.

Another point is, if two views need to access the same code to call the external provider you will end up having duplicated c# code in your views.

A better approach would be to centralize that external Api code behind some kind of service layer, and use RenderAction or Action helpers to initiate the communication with that service layer.